# Any one can make sense of connStateInterface?

Tags: go

```
func (c *conn) setState(nc net.Conn, state ConnState) {
    ...
    c.curState.Store(connStateInterface[state])
    ...
}

// connStateInterface is an array of the interface{} versions of
// ConnState values, so we can use them in atomic.Values later without
// paying the cost of shoving their integers in an interface{}.
var connStateInterface = [...]interface{}{
    StateNew:      StateNew,
    StateActive:   StateActive,
    StateIdle:     StateIdle,
    StateHijacked: StateHijacked,
    StateClosed:   StateClosed,
}
```

I can't figure out the trick with connStateInterface, how exactly does it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a few things going on here...

The `[...]` declaration creates an actual array instead of a slice, so that indirection is removed. What's being declared here is an array of `interface{}` types... so you might wonder why the weird map-looking notation?

The `StateXXX` variables are simply constants declared further above, so they are ints... so the declaration is actually of the form `index: value`.

Here's a less obfuscated example of that using an array of ints:

```
var i = [...]int{4: 2, 2: 7}
```

This will allocate an array containing:

```
[0, 0, 7, 0, 2]
```

... note that index 2 has 7, index 4 has 2. Not a common way of declaring an array, but it's valid Go.

So going back to the original declaration, just take the example I gave above, and instead of int, make the array of type `interface{}`:

```
var i = [...]interface{}{4: 2, 2: 7}
```

And you'll get a similar array, but with `nil` interface values in place of zeroes.

Getting even closer to the original code, the `StateXXX` constants are just ints, only not literals like in my example.

So, what's the point of all this? Why all the obfuscation?

It's a performance hack. The function `c.curState.Store()` takes an argument of type `interface{}`. If you were to pass it an int, the compiled code would have to fumble about with converting the type on each call. A more clear (though obviously impractical) illustration of this might be:

```
var val interface{}

for i := 0; i < 1000000; i++ {
    // the types are different, compiler has to fumble int vs. interface{}
    val = i
    // do something with val
}
```

Every time you do `val = i` a conversion between `int` and `interface{}` needs to happen. The code you posted avoids this by creating a static lookup table where all the values are *already* of type interface.

Therefore, this:

```
c.curState.Store(connStateInterface[state])
```

is more efficient than this:

```
c.curState.Store(state)
```

Since `state` would, in this case, need to undergo the `int -> interface{}` conversion. In the optimized code, `state` is merely an index looking up a value into an array, the result of which gets you an `interface{}`... so the `int -> interface{}` type conversion is avoided.

I'm not familiar with that code, but I'd imagine it's in a critical path and the nanoseconds or whatever savings shaved off likely makes a difference.

Comment: Shouldn't the array in the example be `[0, 0, 7, 0, 2]` rather than `[0, 0, 7, 0, 4]`?

Comment: Yes indeed, I've edited to fix the example array. Thanks